# On a typical GridView, how to differentiate tags inside a <td>

Tags: javascript

I am working on a GridView and some rows are editable and some rows are not editable. For a particular cell, I can get the cell.tagName that is returning the `<TD>`. How can I get the tag name of it's child? I need to get 'select' and 'div' using the javascript

```
<td class="cl">
<select name="ctrlvcol%3DID%3Bctrl%3DmultizoneDemarcationSLC%3Brow%3D19451111%3Btype%3Dtxt" onchange="getOrder(this.value,19451111)">
</td>

<td class="cl">
<div onchange="getOrder(this.value,60874111)">
<span>
<nobr></nobr>
VALUE
</span>
</div>
</td>
```

Thanks

Comment: try `cell.childNodes` - this will give you a list of it's children, you can traverse it with for loop

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks. When I did cell.firstChild it returned HTMLDivElement & HTMLSelectElement .. Then I tried cell.firstChild.nodeValue which returned undefined. Do you have any idea how cell.firstChild.nodeValue will work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag name of a certain element can be obtained using:

```
element.tagName
```

see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName)

But your question is not this since you seem to know this already. You want to know how to get the child element of such a `td` element. For this you can use the [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) element property to do it:

```
var children = td.childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    // do something with each child as children[i], like:
    switch (children[i].tagName) {
        case 'SELECT':
            // do something with the select
            break;
        case 'DIV':
            // do something else with the div
            break;
    }
}
```

But, unless you are constrained by other project specification, a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) might be very helpful.

In jQuery you would only do something like:

```
var allSelectsDirectlyInTds = $('td > select');
var allDivsDirectlyInTds = $('td > div');

// or for example add events to these elements you are searching for:
$('td > div').on('click', function() { /* do something when the user clicks on the div */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cell's `childNodes` collection.

```
var children = cell.childNodes;
var firstTagName = children[0].nodeName;
```

`childNodes` returns an array-like collection. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes

Comment: If we want to get the parent of the particular <td> ? cell.parentElement ??